# How do I find the source code, in VS code, for a component, after running and seeing it locally?

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I am working on my first front-end project for someone and he send me the souce code to modify some buttons, but because is the first time for me, I cannot find them in the source code due to the app having a lot of files, is there any way to do this in a smart way ?

Answer (score 0):

Open the folder that contains the project in VS Code. Click the search icon, type a fragment of the jsx used to render the component in question, like <MyButton and you should see all of the instances of it. Click on one to open it in the editor and then rightclick on <MyButton in the source code and click "Go to definition."

If you don't know the name of the component then you can do basically the same thing with the caption for the button or its image file name.